# iOS camera tap to focus animation

Tags: ios, camera

Is the iOS Camera app's "tap to focus" animation available somewhere that I can download and use? Preferably an array of images?

Comment: This borderlines on too trivial for the site (we're not looking to be a dictionary or wiki or list that points at specific resources) but I am interested in the "what next" part of your question to see if others can learn how to record any animation on iOS - I'll assume that's what you really are seeking and answer that version of "what next". If I missed your focus, just edit in more details to the question and we can clean up or delete my answer as needed.

Answer (score 2):

I know of none that are worth downloading.

You could easily record it yourself using AirPlay mirroring on the iOS device and a screen recording program like [Reflector](http://reflectorapp.com) and [Screeny](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screeny/id440991524) if you have access to a machine that runs OS X.

Comment: Alright.So I'll manually have to cut it out and create it myself huh?

Comment: That's what I do. I pick a nice out of focus background, or aim the camera at a large poster board of a pleasing color and light pattern and mock things up. You can also green screen it depending on how fancy you want to get in post production.